# SSIS 2014 Package Execution from SQL Agent

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2014

We are running SQL Server 2014 Standard (12.0.4100.1) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard. When we schedule an SSIS package to be ran, it seems to have trouble parsing the parameter values into the command line that is actually ran.

There is a project level connection manager that has the connection string set to use the project level parameter, DB_ConnectionString. There are multiple packages that are having this issue, but they are all architected the same way. The specific error is:

> Argument ""$Project::DB_ConnectionString";"Data "Source=serverName;Initial" "Catalog=dbName;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated" "Security=SSPI;Auto" Translate=False;"" for option "parameter" is not valid.  The command line parameters are invalid.  The step failed.

When I change the step type to "Operating System (CmdExec)", this is the code it is running:

```
/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\folderPath\folderPath\packageName.dtsx\"" /SERVER serverName /Par "\"$Project::BaseDirectory\"";"\"\\srvName\share\\"" /Par "\"$Project::DB_ConnectionString\"";"\"Data Source=serverName;Initial Catalog=dbNAme;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;\"" /Par "\"$ServerOption::LOGGING_LEVEL(Int16)\"";1 /Par "\"$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)\"";True /CALLERINFO SQLAGENT /REPORTING E
```

It seems to be having issues with the "Data Source", "Integrated Security", etc. containing spaces. I've removed the spaces, and that gives me a different message, indicating that it parsed the command correctly but can't resolve the connection string.

Is this simply a bug? Is there anything we can do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the project parameters correctly mapped to environments in the deployed projects? Don't see the /Envreference option outputted.
Look at 
[Using DTEXEC with Packages on the IS Server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2011/07/24/using-dtexec-with-packages-on-the-is-server/)

Comment: We don't use the environments at this point, we just specify the value for each parameter.  I'll try running it using an environment though and see how it goes.

Comment: I put the parameters into an environment and executed it that way and it worked!  Thanks for your help!